# Location of blocked numbers within iTunes backup

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

Tools such as [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) allow you to easily browse through an iTunes backup and it's contents, and then things like the `plist` command for converting preferences down to readable XML. Where would the location of the plist or sqlite DB that contains blocked numbers on an iPhone such as described in the [apple docs](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201229)?

Comment: I do not have iExplorer installed. Can't you make a new contact, block it, and then search for it?

Comment: I've attempted that already through all the decoded plists and sqlite databases I was able to find within my backup, and none of the blocked numbers or their referenced IDs in my contacts book were found. It's why I'm rather lost.

Comment: Just an idea: check that you are making an encrypted backup with iTunes, since unencrypted backups lack certain information, perhaps including blocked numbers. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205220

Answer (score 3):

I looked into your question, and I think it might not be possible to find blocked numbers within a backup (or at least not in a recognizable form). I know that it is possible to find these numbers if you have messages synced with iCloud. Through the messages app on a Mac, you can go to preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), and from there view any blocked numbers that are synced.

[image: Picture-of-settings-messages-preferences]

I am still looking through finding the blocked numbers in the backups myself, but I am unsure that I will find them there. If I come across more I will edit the answer further.

I hope this helps and best of luck of finding the blocked numbers through that backup.

(I am new to StackExchange, so I appreciate any feedback that would help me improve my answers or how/when I answer)

Answer (score 3):

An encrypted backup is required to see the blocked number in a local iTunes backup. Blocked numbers can be found in `Home/Library/Preferences/com.apple.cmfsyncagent.plist`. Thanks for [Ashley](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22953/ashley) for pointing out using encrypted backups.